# Extracting highest values from each column along with ID

Tags: r, sorting, for-loop

I am having some trouble restructuring some data into a more digestible format.  I have a data frame like this (but with many more rows and columns).  The rows are bird species, the columns are forest types:

```
Species Decid Hemlock Mixed Pine Spruce Total
ACFL     0       2     0    2      0     4
AMCR     0       2     0    0      5     7
AMRE    74      18    51   40     43   226
AMRO     3       0     0    3      0     6
BAWW    16      32    27   29     22   126
BBCU     5       2     1    4      5    17
```

What I want to do is write some code in R that will return a data frame that shows only the 5 species that occurred most in each forest type.  In other words, go through each column, find the 5 highest values, then put them in a new data frame along with the associated value in the "Species" column  I tried a few methods include using head(), sort(), etc.  I was thinking I could do a loop, but I cant figure out how to get it.  More specifically, I tried to get the loop to iterate through each column but didn't know how.  I now know that df$i is not correct and df[[i]] didn't work either.  I'm new to loops so maybe I am going about it all wrong.

I'm sure I could get the result I want through some overly convoluted method, but if anyone knows of any quicker methods I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: You want both `Species` and the value for each column?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this with `dplyr` and `tidyr`.  The output is a 'long-format' data frame with the top five Species for each Forest and their corresponding values (note that there may be more than five entries if there is a tie).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% gather(key=Forest,value=value,-Species) %>% #convert to long format
       group_by(Forest) %>% #group by forest type
       top_n(5,value) %>% #select the top five for each group
       arrange(Forest,-value) #sort by forest type and descending value

   Species  Forest value
     <chr>   <chr> <int>
 1    AMRE   Decid    74
 2    BAWW   Decid    16
 3    BBCU   Decid     5
 4    AMRO   Decid     3
 5    ACFL   Decid     0
 6    AMCR   Decid     0
 7    BAWW Hemlock    32
 8    AMRE Hemlock    18
 9    ACFL Hemlock     2
10    AMCR Hemlock     2
# ... with 23 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

Following returns a list with items containing two column data space containing the top Species for each forest. You can change the top number of species using `top_n` - I used 3 here instead of 5.

```
top_n <- 3
lapply(2 : 6, function(i) x[order(x[, i], decreasing=T)[1 : top_n], c(1, i)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version also using tidyverse but using sorting via the `arrange()` function and then grabbing the top 5 items with `slice()`

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
   gather(forest, value, Decid:Total) %>% 
   group_by(forest) %>% 
   arrange(forest, desc(value)) %>% 
   slice(1:5)
```